# iPhone UI libraries?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, custom-controls

Has any one encountered any open source iPhone UI Libraries that are good to use in projects to replace some of the standard controls with ones that are more customizable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master) is facebook's collection of IPhone UI classes originally developed by [Joe Hewitt](http://www.joehewitt.com/).

[TapkuLibrary](http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) from [Devin Ross](http://devinsheaven.com/) is a collection of UI classes for iPhone development.

Comment: Three20 isn't Joe's anymore. It'd be more politically correct to say it belongs to Facebook and Joe was the original creator.